# Reverse rails routing: find the action name from the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I understand how to turn `:controller`, `:action,` `:etc` into a URL.  I'm looking to do the reverse, how can the action that the rails router will call be found from the URL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

someone else might have a shorter way to do this, but if you are just evaluating a URL, then you go to the `ActionController::Routing::RouteSet` class

for a `config.routes.rb`

```
map.resources :sessions
```

the code to find is:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path('/sessions/new', {:method => :get})
#=> {:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'}
```

Right:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path('/sessions/1/edit', {:method => :get})
#=> {:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'edit', :id => 1}
```

Wrong - without the `method` being explicitly added, it will default match to `/:controller/:action/:id`:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path('/sessions/1/edit')
#=> {:controller => 'sessions', :action => '1', :id => 'edit'}
```

If you are within the action and would like to know, it is quite a bit easier by calling `params[:action]`

everything you ever wanted to know about routeset can be found here: http://caboo.se/doc//classes/ActionController/Routing/RouteSet.html#M004878

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like your idea.  Why does: route_set.recognize_path(app.edit_foo_path(1))
return:
 {:controller=>"foos", :action=>"1", :id=>"edit"}

Certanly, rails knows that the action is edit, and the id is 1, not vise-versa?

Comment: it appears to be matching on `/controller/action/id` instead of the RESTful route.  Testing, I was able to get it to work properly by always passing the method, without the method - it always goes to default.  I also edited the post, you want to use 'ActionController::Routing::Routes' instead.

Answer (score 27):

With Rails 3 you can do:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/areas/1')
 => {:controller=>"areas", :action=>"show", :id=>"1"}
```