# Rails 4 list mounted engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 3, I was able to do distinguish mounted (or mountable) engines from "other" engines by calling
`MyEngine::Engine.class.mounted_path`. This does not work in Rails 4 anymore. Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049640/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-engines-in-rails-3-app), railties seem to have been deprecated.

How can I distinguish between mountable engines in Rails 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used suggestions found [here][1] to create my own `mounted_path` method.

I put the following in an initializer file:

```
class Rails::Engine
  def self.mounted_path
    route = Rails.application.routes.routes.detect do |route|
      route.app == self
    end
    route && route.path
  end
end
```

Still looking for better answers.
[1]: [Determine if Journey::Path::Pattern matches current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456321/determine-if-journeypathpattern-matches-current-page)

Answer (score 3):

`Rails::Engine.subclasses`

This will return the mounted engines.

Comment: this returns all engines, such as Coffee, Turbolinks and Devise. I am referring to your own custom mounted engines as shown in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html