# How can I find the controller and action from rails 3 route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

This is basically a rails 3 version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481731/reverse-rails-routing-find-the-the-action-name-from-the-url). Short of parsing it myself, how can I get the components (controller, action, parameters) from a URL string?

The method `ActionController::Routing::Routes#recognize_path` has been [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Routing/RouteSet/recognize_path), and I can't get the one it's been replaced with to work the same way:

```
1.9.3p125 :019 > ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.recognize_path('/accounts/new', {:method => :get})
NoMethodError: undefined method `recognize_path' for ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:Class
```

which makes sense since it's not a static method. Looking at the source didn't enlighten me either. Any pointers would be welcome.

EDIT:

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
Rails 3.2.3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me (Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1.0):

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/accounts/new', {:method => :get})
```